# Azure api management ssl certificate must have a private key

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I have been working on the deployment of an azure api management with a self signed certificate and private key.

Goes without saying that I tested my terraform code a couple of days ago and everything worked just fine and I was able to deploy my infra using terraform, so I deleted the resources group from the portal. Today I wanted to spin up the infra once again but I got the following error:

```
Error: creating/updating API Management Service "demo-apim-testing" (Resource Group "rg-testing-apim"): apimanagement.ServiceClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameters" Message="Invalid parameter: Certificate 'XXXXXXXX' must have a Private Key."
```

And the error points to this resource:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "demo-apim" {
  name     = "demo-apim-test"
  sku_name = "Developer_1"

  hostname_configuration {
    proxy {
      host_name                    = "apim.test.com"
      certificate                  = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)
      certificate_password         = var.ssl_certificate_password
      default_ssl_binding          = true
      negotiate_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
```

I did generated the certificate `.cer` and the `.pfx` as set them as variables:

```
variable "ssl_certificate_path" {
  default = "./certificate.cer"
}

variable "pfx_certificate" {
  default = "./certificate.pfx"
  
}

variable "ssl_certificate_password" {
  default = "XXXXX"
}
```

while in my application gateway I set the same configuration. as follow:

```
  ssl_certificate {
    data     = filebase64(var.pfx_certificate)
    name     = "demo-app-gateway-certificate"
    password = var.ssl_certificate_password
    

  }

  trusted_root_certificate {
    data = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)
    name = "demo-trusted-root-ca-certificate"
  }
```

This same configuration returned `successful` on my latest deployment and was able to test the connection and everything. But today it just does not recognise my certificate anymore.

Can please anyone enlighten me about what am I doing wrong here?

Please if you need more details or you have any question, don't hesitate to ask. thank you so much

Comment: What does `pfx_certificate` point to? If TF worked yesterday and doesn't work today, someone's made a manual change to the system most likely

Comment: it points to a `.pfx` certificate that I am hosting on the same folder. Nobody touched anything because I am the only one working on this. And all what I did yesterday, was to delete the entire infra from azure portal. And today just stopped recognising the ssl cert

Comment: Ah you deleted the infra without using Terraform? Can you afford to reinstate everything from scratch? If so, run `terraform destroy` and then try applying again

Comment: I can just delete the terraform start and deploy again a clean deployment. Will that help?

Comment: No no - the first (unofficial) rule of Terraform is that once it is managed by TF, keep it managed by TF (unless in rare cases). Run `terraform destroy` to tear everything down and then run `terraform apply`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, I destroyed the resource using terraform. I am deploying again, will take about 1 hr to finish and I will be back here with an answer

Comment: I tried to apply again terraform but it fails with the same error. but this time I have this error too, which I believe is related to the private key failing `Error: creating/updating Subnet: (Name "apim-subnets" / Virtual Network Name "out-virtual-network" / Resource Group "rg-hri-testing-apim"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded`

Comment: Can you try with certificate = filebase64(var.pfx_certificate)  instead of certificate = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT I tried with the pfx and indeed it worked just fine. But I don't understand how come the other day it was working just fine even with the wrong configuration. Mystery of life I guess. Thank you so much for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the certificate block supports the base 64 encoded PFX or base 64 encoded X.509 certificate,

You can use the below code:

```
certificate = filebase64(var.pfx_certificate)
```

Instead of

```
certificate = filebase64(var.ssl_certificate_path)
```

So the final code should like below:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "demo-apim" {
  name     = "demo-apim-test"
  sku_name = "Developer_1"

  hostname_configuration {
    proxy {
      host_name                    = "apim.test.com"
      certificate                  = filebase64(var.pfx_certificate)
      certificate_password         = var.ssl_certificate_password
      default_ssl_binding          = true
      negotiate_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
```